# JPEG Viewer can't be called from Process.start

Tags: c#, asp.net, jpeg

Here is my code

```
      if (row.Cells[5].Value.ToString().ToUpper() == "JPG")
      {
          try 
          {
         //     string notepadPath = Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "MSPAINT.exe");
              string notepadPath = Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "JPEGViewer.exe");
              if (File.Exists(notepadPath))
                  Process.Start(notepadPath, location);
              else
                  throw new Exception("Can't locate Notepad");
          }
          catch (Exception ee)
          {
              MessageBox.Show("Exception is " + ee.Message);
          }
      }
```

Even Though the String notepadPath contains the Folder and executable **C:\Windows\system32\JPEGViewer.exe**  the line **  `if (File.Exists(notepadPath))` doesn't find the exe even though it is there. If I attempt to bypass the Exist and perform the  `Process.Start(notepadPath, location);` It throws an exception **The system cannot find the file specified** 
**

Please note that this same code works perfectly when calling *MSPAINT.EXE*

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated,

Comment: MAYBE YOU DON'T HAVE JPEGVIEWER.EXE IN YOUR PATH? OR MAYBE IT DOESN'T EXIST?

Comment: What value has `location`?

Comment: can we get a screenshot of explorer showing JPEGViewer.exe exists?  I cannot find it in System32 on any of my machines.

Comment: If you go to Start > Run > jpegviewer does the program open?

Comment: you have mix the server side programming with the client side and what use can see on the browser.

Comment: The location variable has nothing to do with this issue, since the failure is occurring with this line if (File.Exists(notepadPath)) I made sure that notepadPath has the correct path and exe. the jpegviewer.exe is a lightweight viewer I download and installed in the Windows/system32 folder. I verified it works by manually typing jpegviewer test.jpg at a command prompt and I see the file gets opened.I can also call up the program from Start->Run jpegviewer